# Switch statement in loop with unknown number of repetitions

Tags: java, arrays, loops, switch-statement, do-while

Hi I am doing a little task where I need to build a loop with unknown number of repetitions. I have a problem with my code where when the user enters in a character the output displays infinitely. How do I fix this?

````
String[] action = {"x", "u", "d", "l", "r", "s", "h", "e"}; 

        System.out.println("Please enter an action");

    String input = sc.next();

    char selection;

        do{
            selection = input.charAt(0);

        switch(selection){

            case 'x': System.out.print("Bye!"); 
                break;
            case 'u' : System.out.print("You go one square up.");
                break;
            case 'd': System.out.print("You go one square down.");
                break;
            case 'l': System.out.print("You go one square left.");
                break;  
            case 'r': System.out.print("You go one square right.");
                break;      
            case 's': System.out.print("You search the square for treasure. You find nothing.");
                break;  
            case 'h': System.out.print("You hide, waiting for enemies to come by. It gets boring after about an hour and a half, so you give up.");
                break;  
            case 'e': System.out.print("You eat some food. You regain 0 hit points");
                break;
            case 'z': 
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("I dont understand");
                break;
        }
        }
            while (selection != 'z');
        ```
````

Answer (score 0):

`sc.next()` halts the execution until user does an input. 
However since it is outside the loop, it will not stop to read a new input.
Therefore you need to move the `next()` call into the loop.

```
do{
  String input = sc.next();
  selection = input.charAt(0);

  switch(selection){
  // rest of the code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the users input into the do-while loop as well. So it asks for new input after every iteration. I am currently on my phone so I can not show you. But its an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to read the input character-by-character. Since you already took a word input, you need to start from index 0 and continue moving to the next character in the do-while loop. For that:

```
String[] action = {"x", "u", "d", "l", "r", "s", "h", "e"}; 
        System.out.println("Please enter an action:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();
    char selection;
    int i = 0;
        do{
            selection = input.charAt(i++);

        switch(selection){

            case 'x': System.out.print("Bye!"); 
                break;
            case 'u' : System.out.print("You go one square up.");
                break;
            case 'd': System.out.print("You go one square down.");
                break;
            case 'l': System.out.print("You go one square left.");
                break;  
            case 'r': System.out.print("You go one square right.");
                break;      
            case 's': System.out.print("You search the square for treasure. You find nothing.");
                break;  
            case 'h': System.out.print("You hide, waiting for enemies to come by. It gets boring after about an hour and a half, so you give up.");
                break;  
            case 'e': System.out.print("You eat some food. You regain 0 hit points");
                break;
            case 'z': 
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("I dont understand");
                break;
      }
    } while (i < input.length() && selection != 'z');
```

You need to have another condition inside `while()` to avoid exceeding the size of the input string. Also, I couldn't understand why you need the String array `action` that you created in the beginning.